# What wording makes this double-free-causing call `std::vector<T>::clear()` in `T`'s constructor undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, vector, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, double-free

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Foo;

std::vector<Foo> v;

struct Foo {
    std::string s = std::string(10000, 'x');
    Foo() {}
    Foo(int) { v.clear(); }
};

int main() {
    v.resize(1);  // required, otherwise no double free
    v.reserve(2);  // optional
    v.emplace_back(10);  // causes double free
}
```

Here I call `v.emplace_back` which calls `Foo(int)` which calls `v.clear()` *before `emplace_back` is completed*. Seemingly, `std::vector` is unprepared for that mess and my implementation (Ubuntu 22.04's libstdc++) results in double free: `v[0]` is first destroyed by `clear()`, and later by `v`'s destructor.

What wording in any C++ standard makes the behavior of the program above undefined? I'm "simply" calling some operations on `v`. I don't even access any elements of `v`.

Comment: *I'm "simply" calling some operations on `v`* is accessing the elements of `v`.  `clear` has to destroy all of the elements, including the one that you are currently in the constructor body of.  So you destroy the object before the constructor finishes.

Comment: You are deleting the object before it is (finally) constructed. I guess it fails on trying to delete the uninitialized string. But it may do anything.

Comment: @m2j The string is a data member, it has to be initialized before the constructor body starts.

Comment: @François Andrieux that's right. my bad.

Comment: `clear` invalidates all pointers and references to elements on the vector. This includes any pointer or reference that `emplace_back` might hold onto the object being constructed, or the storage that will be used for that object. I suspect there is no obvious rule against this, and it is only forbidden through a collection of other rules.

Comment: I think [\[basic.life\]p6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.life#6) and [\[class.cdtor\]p2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.cdtor#2) are the likely paragraphs controlling the behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's not what happens in my implementation, but I digress. That explanation raises another question: is the object being `emplace`d into vector considered its content that has to be `clear`ed? My implementation believes it is not: `v.size()` in the constructor is 1, not 2.

Comment: Weirdest code I ever saw

Comment: I don't know about the standard, but self deleting objects just result in UB: they will be destructed again - leading to double-free on all owned resources. There are other examples of such ill-formed code. Does double-free need to be re-emphasized as UB?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an active [LWG issue 2414](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2414) to clarify reentrancy when different member functions of library objects are called. The current wording in [reentrancy] only specifies that it is implementation-defined which library functions are reentrant with regards to themselves (unless overruled by more specific rules).